# Date picker ActiveX excel VBA not responding when created automatically

Tags: excel, calendar, activex, activexobject, vba

Dear (vba) programmers,

I am building a dynamic filter in excel (with vba and ActiveX controls).
I would like to use the Microsoft Date and Time Picker Control, Version 6.0 in Excel 2010.
When I generate a drop down calendar with:

```
Set OLEObj = Sheets("Blad3").OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="MSComCtl2.DTPicker.2",   Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=10, Top:=10, Width:=123, Height:=40)
```

It is placed correctly, but it doesn't function. When I toggle developers mode on and off it functions all of the sudden. This seems like a bug to me or do I have to activate the object or something like that??

I have the same problem as the "first strange thing" of:
http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=47290

Hopefully there is someone with the answer.
Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. This is a problem with `mscomctl` control in Windows. If the `mscomctl.ocx` is not registered in `system32` folder then your Excel won't support that date picker.

You can create customized Date Picker and that won't need any such control as it will be totally a userform with different objects.

Check out [this video](http://youtu.be/z2XIbiyWOFU) to see how it looks like:

**How to Create This?**

1. Create a excel calender in a excel sheet using formulas. Check [this video](http://youtu.be/phzgipX3Q2g) to see how to do it.
2. Then, create a Userform. Add Labels for each day and headers.
3. Set caption of these Labels to cell reference.
4. On label click event - change bgcolor of that label and save value in it's caption.

Rest it is self explanatory if you watch both videos carefully.

If you don't want to create your own date picker then you need to put `mscolctl.ocs` in `system32` folder and execute batch command to execute it.

Once it is there click START>RUN and type `REGSVR32 MSCOMCTL.OCX`